# Rolling mean before specific datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe where df.head(4) looks like this

| order time | delivered time | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 13:03:31 | 2022-11-05 13:33:31 | 30 |
| 2022-11-05 13:20:31 | 2022-11-05 13:54:31 | 34 |
| 2022-11-05 13:34:31 | 2022-11-05 13:59:31 | 25 |
| 2022-11-05 13:58:31 | 2022-11-05 14:30:31 | 32 |

I want to calculate the rolling mean of the past 2 orders for each new order. However the rolling mean should not consider orders which has not been delivered yet

The last row rolling mean should be ((30+34)/2) = 32 and should not take 25 because this order has not been delivered when the last row order was placed

The resulting dataframe should look like this

| order time | delivered time | duration | rolling mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-05 13:03:31 | 2022-11-05 13:33:31 | 30 | NA |
| 2022-11-05 13:20:31 | 2022-11-05 13:54:31 | 34 | NA |
| 2022-11-05 13:34:31 | 2022-11-05 13:59:31 | 25 | 30 |
| 2022-11-05 13:58:31 | 2022-11-05 14:30:31 | 32 | 32 |

I tried the following code

```
def rolling(df):
    dt=df['order time'].values
    df['rolling mean'] = (df.set_axis(dt)
                        .rolling(2)['duration']
                        .mean()
                        .set_axis(df.index)
                        .shift(1)
                      )
    return df

df_result =  df.apply(rolling)
```

However, this is averaging the last 2 orders even if the order is not delivered yet

Comment: Why should the last rolling mean be 32? Shouldn't that be the first rolling mean? And the last rolling mean be (34+25)/2 = 29.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the output you desire.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.2


string = StringIO("""order time delivered time  duration
2022-11-05 13:03:31 2022-11-05 13:33:31 30
2022-11-05 13:20:31 2022-11-05 13:54:31 34
2022-11-05 13:34:31 2022-11-05 13:59:31 25
2022-11-05 13:58:31 2022-11-05 14:30:31 32""")

df = pd.read_csv(string, sep="\\t", engine="python")

df["order time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["order time"])
df = df.set_index("order time")

df["rolling mean"] = df.rolling(
    window=2,
    min_periods=1
)["duration"].mean().shift(periods=2)

print(df)
```

```
                          delivered time  duration  rolling mean
order time                                                      
2022-11-05 13:03:31  2022-11-05 13:33:31        30           NaN
2022-11-05 13:20:31  2022-11-05 13:54:31        34           NaN
2022-11-05 13:34:31  2022-11-05 13:59:31        25          30.0
2022-11-05 13:58:31  2022-11-05 14:30:31        32          32.0
```

## Explanation

You have the `window` set correctly, but if you leave the `min_periods` to the default it will assume the same as `window` ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#:%7E:text=For%20a%20window%20that%20is%20specified%20by%20an%20integer%2C%20min_periods%20will%20default%20to%20the%20size%20of%20the%20window.)).

By changing the `min_periods` to 1, it will calculate the mean using 2 values in the window, except if there's only 1 then it will average that value with itself, e.g. the first value in the series --> 30/1 = 30.

Leaving it like this will result in the following.

```py
df["rolling mean"] = df.rolling(
    window=2,
    min_periods=1
)["duration"].mean().shift(1)
```

```
                          delivered time  duration  rolling mean
order time                                                      
2022-11-05 13:03:31  2022-11-05 13:33:31        30           NaN
2022-11-05 13:20:31  2022-11-05 13:54:31        34          30.0
2022-11-05 13:34:31  2022-11-05 13:59:31        25          32.0
2022-11-05 13:58:31  2022-11-05 14:30:31        32          29.5
```

So we shift it by a period of 2 instead of 1 to get your desired output.

```py
df["rolling mean"] = df.rolling(
    window=2,
    min_periods=1
)["duration"].mean().shift(periods=2)
```

```
                          delivered time  duration  rolling mean
order time                                                      
2022-11-05 13:03:31  2022-11-05 13:33:31        30           NaN
2022-11-05 13:20:31  2022-11-05 13:54:31        34           NaN
2022-11-05 13:34:31  2022-11-05 13:59:31        25          30.0
2022-11-05 13:58:31  2022-11-05 14:30:31        32          32.0
```

## References

- [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)
- [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)